# Laravel 5.2 : How to write query builder with 2 ON in this right join

Tags: laravel

I have this sql syntax

```
    SELECT vehicles.license_plate, vehicles.year, vehicles.status, vehicles.zone_id, vehicles.car_class_id, harga_sewa.value, harga_sewa.description
FROM  `vehicles` 
RIGHT JOIN  `harga_sewa` ON vehicles.zone_id = harga_sewa.zone_id
AND vehicles.car_class_id = harga_sewa.car_class_id
```

How I can write something like this?

```
DB::table('vehicles')
                ->rightJoin('harga_sewa', 'vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id', AND vehicles.car_class_id = harga_sewa.car_class_id)
                ->select(*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
DB::table('vehicles')
            ->rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join) {
                $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
                $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

On mobile, so can't test, but from memory this should work:

```
DB::table('vehicles')
  ->rightJoin('harga_sewa', 'vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id')
  ->rightJoin('harga_sewa', 'vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id')
  ->select('*')
  ->get();
```